# android -The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I get this error :
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131034188, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class .MainActivity$ListAdapter)]

This is what I do , I run a AsyncTask and get json data , then , onPostExecute, I call ListAdapter that makes the data to listview .

```
@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Spots_tab1_json sh = new Spots_tab1_json();
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url + page, Spots_tab1_json.GET);

            if (jsonStr != null) {
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_CONTACTS);
for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                        String onvan = new String(c.getString("onvan").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                        String id = new String(c.getString("id").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                        String dates = new String(c.getString("dates").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                        String price = new String(c.getString("gheymat").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                        HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        contact.put("onvan", onvan);
                        contact.put("img", new String(c.getString("img").getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    }
}
}
} 

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (!isCancelled() && goterr == false) {
            final ListAdapter ladap=new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
            lv.setAdapter(ladap);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    ladap.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }});
        }
    }
```

and after that, my listView is built. I've tested it on several different devices , non of them had any problem but some users told me and I logged and see this error.

What should I do to solve it ? what is wrong ?

thanks you

Comment: why `runOnUiThread(...)`? you can normally call `ladap.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: `onPostExecute(...)`  runs on `UI` thread itself.

Comment: Can you show `doInBackground()` too? More specifically, you may be modifying `contactList` in there, which is presumably still bound to the adapter. This may incidentally lead to an illegal state, when the adapter is accessed while it's been/being modified in the background thread and before `onPostExexute()` is hit.

Comment: @MH is it possible that `onPostExecute()` will get invoked before completing `doInBackground(..)`?

Comment: @Rustam: as far as I'm aware, no, unless you would manually call `onPostExecute()` (which you should *not* of course).

Comment: since you are creating new adapter `ladap` in your `onPostExecute()` method and setting it to listview `lv` so i think no need of notifying the adapter.

Comment: @MH. thanks for the reply , I add onBackground() to my post . What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 9):

Apologies for the belated reply, but it appears as suspected in my earlier comment: you're modifying `contactList` from two different threads.

`ListView` caches the element count and whenever it has to layout its children, it'll check this count againt the current number of items in the bound adapter. If the count has changed and the `ListView` wasn't notified about this, an error is thrown:

```
else if (mItemCount != mAdapter.getCount()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("The content of the adapter has changed but "
    + "ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of "
    + "your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from "
    + "the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() "
    + "when its content changes. [in ListView(" + getId() + ", " + getClass()
    + ") with Adapter(" + mAdapter.getClass() + ")]");
}
```

[Source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/widget/ListView.java#1554).

In other words: that's exactly the error you're getting. In your scenario, the count difference is being caused by modifying the backing dataset from more than a single thread, leading to a synchronization issue: the background thread may modify the dataset, get suspended, and the ui thread may then call `layoutChildren()` without having been notified about the dataset changes.

Now, onto the solution. The easiest one is to make sure you're not modifying the list that is bound to the `ListView`'s adapter from different threads. That is, either make a copy that you can then freely modify, or allocate a new list.

So, do something like this, i.e. in the `onPreExecute()` method of the `AsyncTask`.

New list:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> mNewContactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

A (shallow) copy:

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> mNewContactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(contactList);
```

Then, in `doInBackground()`, add the data to `mNewContactList`. Finally, in `onPostExecute()`, you can:

1. Create a new adapter using `mNewContactList` and set it to the `ListView`.
2. Or (if you didn't make a copy of the original list) add the contents of `mNewContactList` to the already existing `contactList` and call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the `ListView`.

Answer (score 2):

data update and your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() must in the same code block.
for example:

Correct case:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSelectedImages.add(image);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Wrong case:

```
mSelectedImages.add(image);
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```